# Use Camel recipientList got ClassCastException

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I'm trying to use Apache Camel to dynamically specify destination when program running. After changing the recipientList parameter to List of Endpoint will encounter a ClassCastException.

Could anyone who can help to advice if I have missed something?

Thanks a lot.

```
from("jms:queue:jms/XXXQ").recipientList(header("recipientList")); 

List<Endpoint> eps = new ArrayList<Endpoint>(); 
CxfEndpoint endpoint = exchange.getContext().getEndpoint("cxf:bean:configServiceEndpoint", CxfEndpoint.class);

endpoint.setAddress(URL);
endpoint.setWsdlURL(WSDL);
eps.add(endpoint); 

CxfProducer cp = (CxfProducer) endpoint.createProducer();
cp.start();  

exchange.getIn().setHeader("recipientList", eps);

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="configServiceEndpoint" address="${CXFTestSupport.URL}" wsdlURL="${CXFTestSupport.WSDL}" serviceClass="com.company.client.ClientService">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

The exception as the following:

```
2017-05-16 09:24:16,100 13100 WARN  org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener  - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint incompatible with java.lang.String]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint incompatible with java.lang.String
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1619)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:186)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:107)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:699)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:637)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:605)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint incompatible with java.lang.String
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers.transferProtocolHeadersToURLConnection(Headers.java:358)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers.setProtocolHeadersInConnection(Headers.java:310)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setProtocolHeaders(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1288)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:210)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:80)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:100)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:241)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:253)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:174)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:418)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:116)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.NoErrorHandlerBuilder$1.process(NoErrorHandlerBuilder.java:40)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:798)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:304)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
        ... 3 more
    2017-05-16 09:24:16,100 13100 WARN  org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener  - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint incompatible with java.lang.String]
    org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint incompatible with java.lang.String
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1619)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:186)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:107)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:699)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:637)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:605)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfSpringEndpoint incompatible with java.lang.String
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers.transferProtocolHeadersToURLConnection(Headers.java:358)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers.setProtocolHeadersInConnection(Headers.java:310)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setProtocolHeaders(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1288)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:210)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:80)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:100)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:241)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:253)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:174)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:418)
        at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:116)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:91)
        at org.apache.camel.builder.NoErrorHandlerBuilder$1.process(NoErrorHandlerBuilder.java:40)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:798)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:304)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
        ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting

```
List<Endpoint>
```

to the recipientList header but according to the documentation (http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html, "Dynamic Recipient List" -> "Iteratable value") Endpoint objects cannot be used:

> The dynamic list of recipients that are defined in the header must be 
>   iterable such as:
>
> - java.util.Collection
> - java.util.Iterator
> - arrays
> - org.w3c.dom.NodeList
> - a single String with values separated by comma
> - any other type will be regarded as a single value

Comment: Yes correct, so put `cxf:bean:configServiceEndpoint` as a string value in that header

Comment: if it solves it, flag it as answer to your question :)